# Get Json from Localhost

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to get some Json from `http://localhost:3000/clientes`, in Angular 5, and load it into a table.

I can just load Json in table when it is in /assets/

This is the code in `general.component.ts`

```
constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  myVals: string [];

  ngOnInit () {
    this.httpService.get('./assets/person.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myVals = data as string [];   
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

And this is the body of my table

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of myVals">
                 <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{item.ID}}</td>
                 <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{item.Name}}</td>
                 <td class="text-center" style="width: 200px;">{{item.CPF}}</td>
                 <td class="text-center">{{item.body}}</td>
             </tr>
```

I am searching a lot, but nothing that could help me, so far. Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint at 
this.myVals = data as string [];  

does the this.myVals get populated correctly?

Also, I'd replace subscribe with map, after get.
See this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347814/how-to-map-response-object-returned-by-http-service-to-a-typescript-objects-usin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @amy8374 The new `HttpClient` by default formats the response to `JSON` so we no longer need to parse it using `map`

Comment: @Vikas sorry if it is not clear. But my question is: How can I load the Json in localhost:3000/clientes into the table? If I just replace the url in the working code, doesn't work

Comment: If I uderstand correctly, "clients" is a local folder from which you are trying to read a json. In that case show us the folder structure of your app, your pathmay be wrong. However if "clients" is in a different server, I would first hit thr URL and verify that the json is correctly displayed in a browser before moving to parsing it using angular.

Comment: @SamwellTarly the json is in a server, I try it in browser and I can see it

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? It might be a cors issue. Which port is your angular app using?

Comment: It was a cors issue. Thanks for the tip, David

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

```
export interface Items {
  ID: string;//change the type according to your response
  NAME: string;
  CPF:string;
}
```

`import` it into your `general.component.ts.`
and then you can cast the `observable` to type Items Array

```
private url ='http://localhost:3000/clientes';
public myVals=[];
ngOnInit () {
    this.httpService.get<Items[]>(this.url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myVals = data;   
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```